# IBOutlet UITableView is null after View did load

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Here's the basic code (based on Xcode's Tabbed Applicaion Template)

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *movies;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize movies,tableView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Watchlist", @"Watchlist");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"watchlist"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     NSLog(@"tableView = %@", tableView);
}
```

Output

```
tableView = (null)
```

The TableView is connected to File's owner in IB with class is set to ViewController

I really don't get why the tableView is null.
I'm not a complete newbie to Cocoa (but to the iPhone SDK), I created a Single View based Application with a TableView dataSource to see if I was missing something. I got it working in under a minute.

Anybody can help out?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a Navigation controller?  Why are you setting a title?

Comment: No a normal View controller, also i left - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil untouched besides the title and the image names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In interface builder right click `File's Owner` and ensure that the following connections are made:

```
Outlets
tableView - Table View

Referencing Outlets
dateSource - Table View
delegate   - Table View
```

I suspect you may have not made the first connection?

Comment: Made all connections, as I said i got it working with a Singe View based Application easily. I think i read somewhere this can happen when using - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil but after 30 min of search I opened this because I could not find it.

Comment: Are you using the correct nib when you init the viewController? I often put the nib selection logic in the viewController itself as it make's no sense that another object should have a better idea what nib a class should load. If not when you init make sure you pass the correct nib name to use

Comment: Ah you are my hero! I recently refactored the View Controller and of course the strings did not refactor.

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure the nib/xib is included in your current target.**

I just experienced this issue on Xcode5 with iOS7 SDK. Strangely enough, I discovered that the nib wasn't included in my target anymore. I don't know when and why that happened, but it had this strange side effect that most IBOutlets weren't set up properly, even if all connections from code to nib/xib were fine.

For example: my `MKMapView *map` was in my list of subviews on `viewDidLoad:`, but the `IBOutlet MKMapView *map` property in my view controller was still *nil*. After I ticked the "include in target" checkbox, everything worked as expected.